# How to delete unnecessary information in topic modeling (lda)

Tags: r, data-mining, text-mining, lda, topic-modeling

How to delete unnecessary information in topic modeling (lda)

Hello I would like to create topic modeling.
My data is this structure.

```
1. Doesn't taste good to me.
2. Most delicious ramen I have ever had. Spicy and tasty. Great price too.
3. I have this on my subscription, my family loves this version. The taste is great by itself or when we add the vegetables and.or meats.
4. The noodle is ok, but I had better ones.
5. some day's this is lunch and or dinner  on second case
6. Really good ramen!
```

I cleaned the reviews and turned topic modeling. But you can see " ", "26.6564810276031", "character(0)".

```
[,1]             [,2]                [,3]            [,4]                 
 [1,] "cabbag"  ")."                "="             "side"                        
 [2,] "gonna"   "26.6564810276031," ""              "day,"              
 [3,] "broth"   "figur"             "character(0)," "ok."
```

Originally, you could not see these things if you only had the frequency of the words, but you can see these words when you run topic modeling.

What was wrong with me?
How do I fix it?

```
library(tm)
library(XML)
library(SnowballC)

crudeCorp<-VCorpus(VectorSource(readLines(file.choose())))
crudeCorp <- tm_map(crudeCorp, stripWhitespace)
crudeCorp<-tm_map(crudeCorp, content_transformer(tolower))



# remove stopwords from corpus
crudeCorp<-tm_map(crudeCorp, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
myStopwords <- c(stopwords("english"),"noth","two","first","lot", "because", "can", "will","go","also","get","since","way","even","just","now","will","give","gave","got","one","make","even","much","come","take","without","goes","along","alot","alone")
myStopwords <- setdiff(myStopwords, c("will","can"))

crudeCorp <- tm_map(crudeCorp, removeWords, myStopwords)
crudeCorp<-tm_map(crudeCorp,removeNumbers)

crudeCorp <- tm_map(crudeCorp, content_transformer(function(x) 
  gsub(x, pattern = "bought", replacement = "buy")))
crudeCorp <- tm_map(crudeCorp, content_transformer(function(x) 
  gsub(x, pattern = "broke", replacement = "break")))
crudeCorp <- tm_map(crudeCorp, content_transformer(function(x) 
  gsub(x, pattern = "products", replacement = "product")))
crudeCorp <- tm_map(crudeCorp, content_transformer(function(x) 
  gsub(x, pattern = "made", replacement = "make")))


crudeCorp <- tm_map(crudeCorp, stemDocument)



library(reshape)
library(ScottKnott)
library(lda)





### Faster Way of doing LDA 
corpusLDA <- lexicalize(crudeCorp)

## K: Number of factors, ,vocab=corpusLDA$vocab (Word contents)

ldaModel=lda.collapsed.gibbs.sampler(corpusLDA$documents,K=7,
vocab=corpusLDA$vocab,burnin=9999,num.iterations=1000,alpha=1,eta=0.1)

top.words <- top.topic.words(ldaModel$topics, 10, by.score=TRUE)
print(top.words)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways. You can add the unwanted words in your set of stopwords or use regex to remove non-alphanumeric tokens during tokenization.

Comment: I am a beginner and I did not fully understand your answer.

I have removed abbreviations and numbers before making the lad model. Do you have to do it after you make it? I would like to give more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a simple three steps mechanism described bellow.

1. Extract words from text by different delimiters such as space,
   '.', and ','.
2. Clean your texts by correcting the words, removing
   the stopwords, stemming words, ...
3. Using some measures to find out the importance of each word, such as Term Frequency (TF), Inverse Document Frequency (IDF), TFIDF, and ...